# How can I make an unclipped subview receive touch events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a small custom view that I use as a button.  I make this happen with a simple `UIButtonTypeCustom`, which I include as a subview over the bounds of the view.  Since the view is small, however, I want to increase the size of the hit target.  This is easily done (one would think) by setting the frame of my button to be larger than the bounds of the custom view and setting `clipsToBounds` to NO.  This works for the visual (the custom button draws outside the parent view) but it does not receive `touchUpInside` events on the area outside of the parent view.  How do I make the button receive `touchUpInside` events?

```
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame: frame]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;

    // ... various image views and labels ...

    UIButton *touchArea = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    touchArea.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: .3]; // so I can see the bounds
    CGRect touchAreaFrame = self.bounds;
    CGFloat checkboxHitTargetExtension = 7;
    touchAreaFrame.origin.y -= checkboxHitTargetExtension;
    touchAreaFrame.size.height += (checkboxHitTargetExtension * 2);
    touchArea.frame = touchAreaFrame;
    [self addSubview: touchArea];

    // ... add listeners etc ...
  }
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pointInside:withEvent: to define whether or not a specific point is "inside" the View. See the UIView reference for more info.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Also checkout CGRectOffset its very handy for making a CGRect bigger.

Comment: Nice!  This is just what I needed.  I can return YES after making the calculation against the button frame, and then it's golden.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button not a child of the view but a sibling to the view, and positioned on top of it, and then there are no clipping issues on the touches to the button.

Comment: It's not that I can't do that, I just am trying to solve this particular issue in general, so that I can get a bit better compartmentalization in my views